# Export/import files .jsx in React

Tags: reactjs, import, export, components

i recently tried to make separate files .jsx in React. I made couple of them with `export default name` / `import name from ./name.jsx'`. But there comes problem. First i had imported Route and Links from `react-router` and console said *it can't find Links*, i found on stackoverflow to change it to `react-router-dom`, so i did it, and now console says *i forgot to export some components*. I can't find solution :( Could anyone help me ?

Here's my project :

https://github.com/tafarian/Portfolio

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './../css/style.scss';
import {
    Router,
    Route,
    Link,
    IndexLink,
    IndexRoute,
    hashHistory
} from 'react-router-dom';
import Template from './Template.jsx'
import Projects from './Projects.jsx'
import Home from './Home.jsx'
import AboutMe from './AboutMe.jsx'
import Contact from './Contact.jsx'
```

Comment: put the code here, too much work to go to link, my guess is your path is wrong

Comment: i added code from main file app.jsx in topic :)

Comment: console says is ambigous. Add the steps you take to get the problem and exact problem

Comment: Okay so first i had only App.jsx file, and in this file i had every single component i wrote. Then i started making separate files for each of component i had, then i added export line in every file and import in main app.jsx file. In file named Template.jsx i used Header and Footer components so I imported them in Template.jsx file and Template.jsx to main App.jsx

Answer (score 0):

Such error as

> "Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `App`.

means that you are trying to create an undefined component, and as it said in error - usually this happens when you forget to export component or the component that you are importing does not exist.

When there is a lot of components and it's hard to find which one is "bad" I place a breakpoint at `console.error(message);` in React code and go up the stacktrace to the function `createElement` and it's arguments. Usually it helps me to identify the problem.

The main problem, is that your code is not compatible with react-router@4.
In this version you can not pass `children` and `component` to `Route` at the same time.
Also, there is no such a thing as `IndexRoute` and you should use `BrowserRouter` instead of `Router`, or you should pass an `history` object.

Take a look at the documention: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/philosophy

And here is fixed version of yout app.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './../css/style.scss';
import {
    BrowserRouter,
    Route,
    Link,
    hashHistory
} from 'react-router-dom';
import Template from './Template.jsx'
import Projects from './Projects.jsx'
import Home from './Home.jsx'
import AboutMe from './AboutMe.jsx'
import Contact from './Contact.jsx'

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

    class App extends React.Component {
        state = {
            loading: true,
        };

        componentDidMount() {
            setTimeout(() =>
                this.setState({
                    loading: false
                }), 2500);
        }

        render() {

            if(this.state.loading === true) {
                return (
                    <div id="preloader">
                        <div id="loader"></div>
                    </div>
                )
            }

            return(
                <BrowserRouter history={hashHistory}>
                    <Template>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                        <Route path='/aboutme' component={AboutMe} />
                        <Route path='/projects' component={Projects} />
                        <Route path='/contact' component={Contact} />
                    </Template>
                </BrowserRouter>
            )
        }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(
        <App />,
        document.getElementById('app')
    );
});
```